Snap is throwing an authorization exception
System info:
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

When I run snap list, I get the following exception:

error: cannot list snaps: cannot add authorization: user: unknown userid 1532788159

I am also not able to open up firefox, or the snap store.

Using this this bug report (which referred to this question) I was able to at least get back to a working state with
sudo snap revert snapd

Which from my understanding simply undoes the last upgrade of snapd.
